# Moments of the Riemann Zeta function

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I was reading a paper on the moments of the Riemann zeta function where I have found the following equation.

Let $\sigma_{\alpha,\beta}(n)=\sum_{n_1n_2=n}n_1^{-\alpha}n_2^{-\beta}=n^{-\alpha-\beta}\sum_{n_1n_2=n}n_1^{\alpha}n_2^{\beta}$, where $\sigma_{\lambda}(n)=\sum_{d|n} d^{\lambda}$ and $\alpha,\beta$ are small complex numbers. Further we have

\begin{align*}
A_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta}(s) =\frac{\zeta(1+s+\alpha+\gamma)\zeta(1+s+\alpha+\delta)\zeta(1+s+\beta+\gamma)\zeta(1+s+\beta+\delta)}{\zeta(2+2s+\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta)},
\end{align*}
where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ are small complex numbers. Claim: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sigma_{\alpha,\beta}(n)\sigma_{\gamma,\delta}(n)}{n^{1+s}}=A_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta}(s).$$

I can not understand how does the above equality hold.

Comment: Does $\sigma$ take two parameters, or one? You wrote: Let $\sigma_{\alpha,\beta}(n)=\dots$ and also: "where $\sigma_{\lambda}(n)=\dots$"

Comment: It seems like you can show $\sigma_{\alpha,\beta}(n)\sigma_{\gamma,\delta}(n)$ is multiplicative, so you get a product formula for the left side of the claim and a product formula for the definition of $A.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer.

Using the product formula for $\zeta$ we get the product term for $p$ in the definition of $A$ is:

$$\frac{1-p^{-(2+2s+\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta)}}{\left(1-p^{-(1+s+\alpha+\gamma)}\right) \left(1-p^{-(1+s+\alpha+\delta)}\right) \left(1-p^{-(1+s+\beta+\gamma)}\right) \left(1-p^{-(1+s+\beta+\delta)}\right)}\tag1 $$

Also, $\sigma_{\alpha,\beta}$ and $\sigma_{\gamma,\delta}$ are both multiplicative, so the left side of your claim is the product of terms:

$$f_p(s)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sigma_{\alpha,\beta}(p^k)\sigma_{\gamma,\delta}(p^k)}{p^{k(1+s)}}\tag 2$$

You need to show (1) an (2) are equal.

Presumably, you need the calculation that:

$$\begin{align}\sigma_{\alpha,\beta}(p^k)&=\sum_{i=0}^{k}(p^i)^{\alpha}(p^{k-i})^\beta\\
&=\frac{p^{(k+1)\alpha}-p^{(k+1)\beta}}{p^\alpha-p^{\beta}}
\end{align}$$

After that, things get even messier, but you should be able to get a formula for $f_p.$

If they are the same, the formula for (2) is going to look like a partial fraction form for the formula (1).